# CA2135 and CA2122 battle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, fxcop

I have a class that hits an Active Directory. It does looks up a user on the domain and checks their grouping. Here is my function definition:

```
[DirectoryServicesPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
public bool IsUserMemberOfGroup(String userName, String groupName)
```

I get error [CA2135](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997569.aspx). So I change it to use Security critical as it states in the MSDN page:

```
[SecurityCritical]
public bool IsUserMemberOfGroup(String userName, String groupName)
```

Now, I get error CA2122, which asks me to change it back to using [LinkDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182303.aspx). Short of supressing this error, is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect that the CA2122 rule has not been fully updated to work with level 2 transparency.  While it recognizes a SecurityCritical assembly-level attribute, it ignores a SecurityCritical type- or member-level attribute in an APTCA assembly.  It's probably safe to add the SecurityCritical attribute and suppress the CA2122 violation, but you might also want to verify that code that lacks unrestricted DirectoryServicesPermission can't actually call into your method.